# Why 'imshow' in skimage does not work properly with bit shift

Tags: python, scikit-image

I tried to display bit planes images with bit shift method.
However I always get a whole black image for all subplots.

```
import skimage.io as io  
import skimage.util as util  
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
from skimage.color import rgb2gray  
import skimage.filters as fl  

path = 'D:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Image_Processing/Data/16.png'
w = io.imread(path)  

# convert the colorful image to a grey scale image  
gray = rgb2gray(w)  
plt.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'), vmin=0, vmax=1)  
plt.show()  

# bit shift for creating bit plane images  
bps = [(np.uint8(gray) >> i) % 2 for i in range(8)]  

# plot 8 subplots to show the result  
for i in range(8):  
    plt.subplot(3, 3, i+1)  
# add color map to assure the present color is in grey scale  
    io.imshow(bps[i], , cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))  
    plt.axis('off')  
    plt.show()
```

[Original grey scale picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKKQN.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjbJZ.png)

Also there will be some warning with the execution result:

> D:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe D:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Image_Processing/read_image.py
>   D:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io_plugins\matplotlib_plugin.py:75: UserWarning: Low image data range; displaying image with stretched contrast.
>     warn("Low image data range; displaying image with "
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

By the way, if I used filter and threshold from otsu,yen,li.
I will get the expected result.

```
thresh = fl.threshold_otsu(gray)
binary = gray >= thresh
io.imshow(binary)
plt.show()
```

Could you please tell me where I get wrong with the original method?
In some other threads mentioned about the loss of converting pictures from one category to another.
Moreover, I could also get successful result by using pure opencv method.

I have checked the following related threads, but I still have no idea how to fix this problem:

[skimage issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1623)

[bit plane slicing](https://theailearner.com/2019/01/25/bit-plane-slicing/)

[threshold method](https://www.cnblogs.com/denny402/p/5131004.html)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I misused the numpy unsigned integer transformation, since the original grey array contains unsigned float numbers between 0 and 1.
First, I need to make grey's intensity into float numbers which are greater than 1.

```
bps = [(np.uint8(gray*255) >> i) % 2 for i in range(8)]
```

Then, the problem is solved.